# How does Ronnie get out of the neighbor's house while videotaping?

Tags: plot-explanation, disturbia

In Disturbia (2007), how does Ronnie get out of the neighbor's house while videotaping? Ronnie just suddenly appears in the closet and I don't think it's explained how he gets there.

Answer (score 1):

When Ronnie finds out that the neighbor is in his home, Ronnie tries to run and hide saying something like "he is inside the house.", during this, the signal between Ronnie and Kale is lost. As Kale has already figured out that the neighbor is a killer, he's worried that something might have happened to his friend and leaves his house premises, creates a scene and police arrives. But Ronnie is too afraid to show up in front of the cops because he broke into someone's house. While everyone including cops is arguing in front of the neighbor's house, Ronnie sneaks out of neighbor's house and hides in the closet (it was not shown in the movie but I had to assume.). The same thing Ronnie explains to Kale in the latter scene.